# Getting Error: no stream handler and Error: stream finishing on fflate for Browser/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser, zip, fflate

I have been following the [fflate readme](https://github.com/101arrowz/fflate/blob/master/README.md) to end up with code which splits PDFs into parts and saves the parts into a zip file. The core function is here:

```
export function splitPdfAndExport(
  pdf: PDFDocument,
  splitAfterMarks: Array<number>,
): Promise<Blob> {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    const streams: Array<any> = []

    const zip = new fflate.Zip()
    zip.ondata = (err, dat, final) => {
      console.log('ZIP', err, dat, final, err instanceof Error)
      if (!err) {
        // output of the streams
        streams.push(dat)
        if (final) {
          res(new Blob(streams, { type: 'application/octet-stream' }))
        }
      } else {
        return rej(err)
      }
    }

    let previousPage = 0
    splitAfterMarks.forEach(async pageI => {
      const sub = await PDFDocument.create()
      const pages: Array<number> = []

      while (previousPage < pageI) {
        pages.push(previousPage++)
      }

      let start = pages[0]
      let end = pages[pages.length - 1]

      const name =
        start === end ? `page.${start}.pdf` : `page.${start}-${end}.pdf`

      const copiedPages = await sub.copyPages(pdf, pages)
      for (const page of copiedPages) {
        sub.addPage(page)
      }
      const data = await sub.save() // returns ArrayBuffer

      const zipFile = new fflate.ZipDeflate(name, {
        level: 7,
      })

      zip.add(zipFile)

      zipFile.push(data, true)
    })

    zip.end()
  })
}
```

However, it seems to be logging that `ZIP Error: stream finishing` right away and what I download as the `Blob` is basically an empty/corrupt zip file. Here's the rest of the code (using `pdf-lib`, which seems to split the PDF just fine, I manually checked that the splitting results in valid PDFs locally):

```
const handleExport = async () => {
  if (buffer) {
    const pdf = await PDFDocument.load(buffer)
    const zip = await splitPdfAndExport(pdf, splitAfterMarksNumbers)
    downloadBlob(zip, 'split.pdf.zip')
  }
}

let a: HTMLAnchorElement

try {
  a = document.createElement('a')
  a.style.display = 'none'
  document.body.appendChild(a)
} catch (e) {}

export function downloadBlob(blob: Blob, fileName: string) {
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  a.href = url
  a.download = fileName
  a.click()
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
}
```

Any idea why it's not working for me? Do I need to add some sort of handler/hook to handle the stream in the callback somehow? I didn't see that in the docs. And the [error codes in the src](https://github.com/101arrowz/fflate/blob/ef157f096c70c43187323c341a9bfb956e29ae83/src/index.ts#L198-L214) don't lead to any clues.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It was because my `Promise` had a `forEach(async () => ...)` but the parent didn't have async, so the stream was ending before any files were sent. It's working now:

```
export async function splitPdfAndExport(
  pdf: PDFDocument,
  splitAfterMarks: Array<number>,
): Promise<Blob> {
  return new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
    const streams: Array<any> = []

    const zip = new fflate.Zip()
    zip.ondata = (err, dat, final) => {
      console.log('ZIP', err, dat, final, err instanceof Error)
      if (!err) {
        // output of the streams
        streams.push(dat)
        if (final) {
          res(new Blob(streams, { type: 'application/octet-stream' }))
        }
      } else {
        // return rej(err)
      }
    }
    // const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(docmentAsBytes)

    const numberOfPages = pdf.getPages().length

    let previousPage = 0
    const marks = splitAfterMarks.concat([numberOfPages])
    for (const pageI of marks) {
      const sub = await PDFDocument.create()
      const pages: Array<number> = []

      while (previousPage < pageI) {
        pages.push(previousPage++)
      }

      let start = pages[0]
      let end = pages[pages.length - 1]

      const name =
        start === end ? `page.${start}.pdf` : `page.${start}-${end}.pdf`
      // copy the page at current index
      const copiedPages = await sub.copyPages(pdf, pages)
      for (const page of copiedPages) {
        sub.addPage(page)
      }
      const data = await sub.save()

      const zipFile = new fflate.AsyncZipDeflate(name, {
        level: 9,
      })

      // Always add streams to ZIP archives before pushing to those streams
      console.log('adding', name)
      zip.add(zipFile)

      console.log('pushing', name, data)
      zipFile.push(data, true)
    }

    console.log('ending')
    zip.end()
    console.log('ended')
  })
}
```